# Sci fi book with a one-man worldwide army

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book between 5 and 10 years ago. I really can't remember any of the story (I've had it on my mind for two days now), all I remember is this scene.

A female protagonist is beside a bridge on an alien planet river with boyfriend/husband when the antagonists try to kill her. The first she knows is loud clangs, it turns out that Planetary Defence has either 'transporter beamed' or 'rapid tractor beamed' a cloaked Armoured Personnel Carrier between her and the bullets.

A very fast firefight happens and the bad guys are gone. She is then introduced to The Planetary Army, this proves to be one guy who has like enhancements and controls loads of mech fighting machines.

Comment: There is a one-man army planetary defense in the *Golden Ecumene* trilogy by John C. Wright. I don't. however, recall the exact scene you describe.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Oecumene

Comment: There is a one-man system-wide defense in the Void Trilogy called the Deterrence Fleet (justly classified 'insanely awesome' by TVTropes - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/VoidTrilogy), but it doesn't look like it

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen yes!  in book 2 this happens:- “Yes ma’am. I carry templates for all possible weapons and other combat systems in my armor, with a long-range pseudo-matter projector, so I can project units of equipment, and fighting machines into my environment, as needed. The thing I put between you and the blast, that was an Iron Wizard Heironymous Fifth-Era War Car with attached entrenching blade …”She blinked. “What?”Atkins spoke in a voice of polite surprise: “You did not notice a large, square-treaded vehicle of heavy mobile armored cavalry appear on the deck between you and the blast ?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen please post as an answer and I'll accept, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***The Golden Oecumene* by John C. Wright**

Wright's far-future post-singularity [*Golden Oecumene* trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Oecumene) (2002-03), a.k.a. *The Golden Age Trilogy*, sports a one-man planetary defense system. The guy, named Atkins, is seriously augmented and is in pseudo-telepathic contact with all defense systems. He can control an orbital laser so precisely that he can perform microsurgery on a person's brain without them even noticing. In volume 2, *The Phoenix Exultant*. Atkins teams up the exiled protagonist's wife Daphne,  and it is probably their first encounter that you recall.

[image]