# Novel about a planet that relies on one soldier - the last soldier in history - to defend it

Tags: story-identification, novel, military-sf

Trying to find a book. One character is the last soldier in history. After a long period (thousands of years?) of peace and civilization, a planet has one guy - the last soldier - who lives alone in a scenic rural place (maybe by a lake or ocean) and is solely responsible for defense of the planet. He has immense skills and may be very old.

Events turn out that he must fight - he controls a vast fleet of space warships, futuristic weapons, etc. He fights with these, and I think wins.

It *might* be an Ian M. Banks *Culture* novel. If not, I think it dates from roughly the same era (maybe 1990-2010).

Comment: Also asked at https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/585542/. Might be the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239218/sci-fi-book-with-a-one-man-worldwide-army

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Indeed it is the same, and my answer (originally a comment) has been accepted. I guess this makes one of them a duplicate.

Comment: I made a judgment call, and made this one the duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That could be one of the books of the [Golden Oecumene trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Oecumene) by John C. Wright, published in 2002-2003. According to the Wikipedia, the "last soldier" character, Atkins, fits your description:

> The entire military is made up of one man, Atkins, who most of the society has forgotten.

I remember reading these books at least 15 years ago, and Atkins does live in a rural setting, is immensely powerful, and in full control of a vast armada of war machines.

Comment: Thanks. I don't recall reading that trilogy but I have read John C. Wright, so there's an excellent chance that's it and I just forgot the title. I'll have look at my bookshelf.